# Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить лого DR.POLNER при 990 px и меньше ровно по центру?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поставить лого DR.POLNER при 990 px и меньше ровно по центру?
Сайт на бутстрап http://anton.ru.xsph.ru/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .logo {
      font-family: SFProDisplay-Black;
      font-size: 36px !important;
      font-weight: 400;

      /* добавить вот эти стили */
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto !important;
      max-width: 335px;
  }
}
```

Но примерно с 480px нужно будет эти стили отменить и сильно уменьшить логотип, чтобы он не перекрывал бургер меню.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.Сейчас попробовал добавить 
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
Помогло)